# How to create Line string in google Maps like Here Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heremaps

this code is to create linestring in Here Maps, I tried to find the same thing in google maps but I couldn't

```
this.GetCoordinates = function (polyPoints) {
        var strips = new H.geo.LineString();

        for (var i = 0; i < polyPoints.length; i++) {
            strips.pushPoint(new H.geo.Point(polyPoints[i].lng, polyPoints[i].lat));
        }
        return strips;
    }
```

the returned stripe value in the console is like the following

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation/examples for Polylines in the Google Maps Javascript API v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in nodeJS:

```
const gpoly = require('google-polyline')

const decodedPath = gpoly.decode(encodedPath);
console.log(`decodedPath`,decodedPath); // array of [lat,lng]
```

in JS for browser:

```
const decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath);
```